# How do I refresh a materialized view with activejdbc?

Tags: activejdbc

I've tried using `Base.exec` / `new DB("default").exec("refresh materialized view concurrently ...` and neither work. No errors, but the statement isn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. Not sure why, but `Base.exec` won't work, only `Statement.executeUpdate`.

```java
// Open your connection
String sql = "refresh materialized view concurrently MY_VIEW";
try {
    Connection conn = new DB("default").connection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    conn.commit();
    stmt.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it might be related to the fact that `Base.exec()` uses `PreparedStatement` and you are using just a `Statement`. Might be some other idiosyncrasy with the driver

Comment: Also, you can replace `Connection conn = new DB("default").connection();` with `Connection conn = Base.connection();`, see more at: http://javalite.io/database_connection_management#db-and-base-classes